# When to use Functional Interface vs Function<T, Y>

Tags: java, functional-interface

I am using Java 11, and we have two ways of passing in functions as an argument.

- functional interface
- `Function<T, Y>`

Now I am not able to find anything on when to use which one. I can figure that we can use a generic functional interface over a `Function<T,Y>` when we either don't want to pass any arguments or have more than 1 arguments. Also when we don't want to return anything from the method.

But let's say if we have a use case where we want to pass in 1 argument and receive 1 value back as an output. In this case, is there a recommendation on what we should pick and why? Or is it that we can pick whichever we like based on codebase uniformity.

Comment: "where we want to pass in 1 argument and receive 1 value back" use the standard thing: `Function`. Unless you want to allow that function to do something like throw a checked exception, or you need the interface to have specific annotations. Note that `@FunctionalInterface` isn't necessary either.

Comment: You can pick whatever you want. If you need a clear name for the interface (instead of `Function`) or a clear function name (instead of `apply`), you can create your own interface. Another case I can think of is when you need some default/static methods which aren't defined in the `Function` interface.

Comment: I don't get it. `Function<T, Y>` *is* a functional interface. `@FunctionalInterface` is an optional annotation for functional interfaces. It isn't an alternative to `Function<T, Y>`.

Comment: @khelwood I think the question was "When should I create my own functional interface with a function which accepts 1 argument and returns a value"?

Comment: @geobreze yes, that's the question.

Comment: @iam.Carrot I think your post shouldn't mention the annotation `@FunctionalInterface`, as your question has little to do with this annotation. You should replace it with just *"functional interface"*.

Comment: @MCEmperor sure I'll update it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me just cite Item 44 "Favor the use of standard functional interfaces" of Effective Java:

> If one of the standard functional interfaces does the job, you should generally
> use it in preference to a purpose-built functional interface. This will make
> your API easier to learn, by reducing its conceptual surface area, and will provide
> significant interoperability benefits, as many of the standard functional interfaces
> provide useful default methods. The Predicate interface, for instance, provides
> methods to combine predicates.

`Function<T,Y>` is a `@FunctionalInterface`. `Function<T,Y>` is a built-in functional interface that has the annotation `@FunctionalInterface`. You have what you need with `Function<T,Y>` and shouldn't create a custom `@FunctionalInterface`.

Comment: I don't understand how is this relevant to this question. This citation states that we should prefer using Built-in functional interfaces as opposed to rebuilding our own functional interfaces as long as the functionality or use case is the same. However the question is if I have a use case where I don't have a built-in functional interface, need to pass one arg as input and get one arg in return, should I use a `Function<T,Y>` or a `@FunctionalInterface`?

Comment: edited the answer to elaborate

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarity. I wasn't thinking it from that perspective.